# Quadratic formula in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$(y')^2 + y' =\frac{y}{x} \tag{0}$$

The solution of this differential equation involves using the quadratic formula for a quadratic in terms of $y'$ but I'm a bit bothered that we get a $ \pm$ when we do that:

$$y'  =- \frac12 \pm \sqrt{\frac{4y}{x} +1} \tag{1}$$

And then we could do $y=xt$ and solve but how exactly do we understand the plus or minus quantity which we get in step-1? It seems that the procedure of completing the quadratic formula generates two differential equation which solves the one in (0). So, should I solve both ones and the actual solution for (0) is a linear combination of both?

Comment: I think you can split yur problem into two cases. And solve both cases independently-

Comment: @TitoEliatron my main problem is interpretting and secondly would the actual diff eqn's soln be linear combination of both solns?

Comment: Yes, you solve both and then you will have to paste the solutions together. Each time $y'$ changes sign, you pass from one solution to the other.

Comment: I didn't understand how the changing sign of y' suggests changing solutions from one to another. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: This was not correct. Each time $y'$ has a double root, that is, if $y'=-\frac12$, you can switch branches of the root without losing the defining characteristic that an ODE solution should be continuously differentiable. The equation is not linear, thus there is nothing to do with linear combinations. One could check if the term under the root defines an extra solution, $y=-\frac x4$, which appears to be not the case.

Comment: @Buraian: I understand your difficulty, I haven't been very clear. Right now I gotta go, I hope to find some time later to try and illustrate my point with some formulas.

Comment: @Giuseppe Negro no problem and thank you

Comment: @Lutz Lehman, can you explain this branch switch concept? I know branches of functions but not sure how the concept applies to differential equations

Comment: I have now corrected my solution, you may see.

Comment: My remark is only correct if the square root is extended in some way, I prefer the signed variant ${\rm sign}(x)·\sqrt{|x|}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ as that can easily be mollified to $\frac{x}{\sqrt{\max(\epsilon,|x|)}}$. Without that solutions stop hard at the line $y=-x/4$ where the double root occurs. As the slope $-1/2$ of the vector field is larger than the slope of the critical line, both solution families try to cross perpendicularly into the region where the expression under the root is negative. So no continuation is possible, no branch to choose.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm sorry where the vector fields come in from? Are you visualizing this as some sort of one form field?

Comment: The vector field is $(1,y'(x))$ in the xy-plane. Obviously, here that has two solutions, with two vectors per point. You could also take the direction field of an associated differential form.

Comment: @Raffaele : How did you compute this? How did you get from an exponent $1/p$ to the exponent $x/y-1$? Per equation, $x/y=1/(p(1+p))=1/p-1/(p+1)$

Comment: @LutzLehmann One hour ago the answer was different :)

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28dy%2Fdx%29%5E2+%2B+dy%2Fdx+%3D+y%2Fx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding upon the comments by @Lutz Lehmann. Given

$$\tag{1}
y'^2+y'=\frac{y}{x}
$$

Let us denote

$$\tag{2}
y'_{\pm}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4y_{\pm}}{x}+1}
$$

These are two separate differential equations. For a given initial condition, solving (2) for $y_{\pm}$ yields two permissible solutions to (1). The solution of (1) will *not* be a linear combination of solutions to (2). Demanding that $y$ is real shows there is a region $y<-x/4$ in which there are no solutions to (1) or (2), which also restricts the initial condition.

A plot is helpful:

[image]

The arrows are the vector fields $(1,y'_{\pm})$, plotted as a function of $x$ and $y$ using eq. (2). You could arbitrarily decide that from eg. $1<x<2$, your chosen solution evolves according to $y_+$, then from $2<x<3$ it evolves according to $y_-$, and so on. However, doing so would render your solution non-differentiable at those 'crossover points'$^\dagger$.

Near the critical line $y=-x/4$, the square root $\to 0$ in eq. (2) and we have $y_+' \sim y_-'\sim-1/2$, so the vector field is approximately $(1,-1/2)$. The direction of the critical line is $(1,-1/4)$ so *both solutions $y_{\pm}$ (can) flow towards/ past the critical line*.

For a given initial condition, the two solutions to (1) are:

1. The solution $y_+$. For certain initial conditions $y(x_0)=y_0$ this will exist for all $x>x_0$, otherwise it meets the critical line at some $x^*$ and ceases to exist for $x>x^*$.
2. The solution $y_-$ until it meets the critical line at some $x^*$.

$\dagger$ **If** it were the case that eg. $y_-$ flows towards but $y_+$ flows away from the critical line, then we could patch together solutions there, and the patched solution would still have a continuous derivative, since $y'_+=y'_-$ on the critical line.

Comment: How did you get this vector field?

Comment: Intuitively: pick a point $y_0(x_0)$, which would be at the co-ordinates $(x_0,y_0)$. If we increase $x_0$ by some amount, say $\delta x$, this point flows to the point $(x_0 + \delta x, y_0 + y' \delta x)=(x_0,y_0)+(\delta x, y' \delta x)$. So the direction of the flow is $\delta x(1,y')$

Answer (score 2):

Incomplete solution:

Let $y'=p$, then the ODE is
$$p^2+p=\frac{y}{x} \implies x=\frac{y}{p^2+p}~~~~~(1)$$
D. (1) w.r.t. $y$ and write $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{p}$ to get
$$p^3+p^2=-y(2p+1)\frac{dp}{dy} \implies \int \frac{dy}{y}=-\int\frac{2p+1}{p^3+p^2}dp$$
$$\ln Cy=\frac{1}{p}-\ln p+\ln(1+p) \implies y=\frac{(1+p)e^{1/p}}{Cp}~~~~(2)$$
Putting this in (1), we get $$x=\frac{ e^{1/p}}{Cp^2}~~~~(3)$$
(2) and (3) give the complete solution of the first order ODE (1) in terms of one undetermined constant $C$, here $p$ acts as a real parameter. One may eliminate $p$ between (2) and (3) to get the cartesian solution with one constant $C$. Se the solution $y(x)$ for $C=1,2,3$

[image]

Comment: In differentiate with y step, why were you able to treat x as constant

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks you may see my solution now.

Comment: @Buraian Thanks you may see my solution now.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks I have corrected it now.

Comment: I still don't get how you differentiated with 'y', also I think you are missing an integral sign in that step

Comment: i have edited it, you may see.

Comment: $x=\frac{y}{p^2+p} \implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{(p^2+p)-y(2p+1)(dp/dy)}{(p^2+p)^2}=\frac{1}{p}$

Comment: By the way what is the answer of this question in your book, that also should help you. The idea being diff w.r.t $y$ is to have an ODE in two varables: $y,p$.

Comment: One could clean up the final parametrization, replace $C$ with $1/C$ and $p=1/t$, then $y=C(1+t)e^t$ and $x=Ct^2e^t$. The same point $(x,y)$ can have two solutions to $y/x=(1+t)/t^2$, $y/x+1/4=(1/2+1/t)^2$, with the corresponding $C$ values, so this single-parameter family should provide the double cover with solutions that the degree 2 of the equation indicates.